# Python making two of the same image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to apply watermarks to photos. I have a black one and a white one. I am trying to open an image, then apply each watermark to the photo but separately, and then save both versions. So the end product would be two of the original image, one with the black watermark only, and one with the white. My issue is it is applying both watermarks and saving them both on there.

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageTk
import os

from msvcrt import getch

def watermark(event):

blackWatermark = Image.open("Watermark(Black).png")
whiteWatermark = Image.open("Watermark(White).png")
fileLocation = str(fileEntry.get())

#window = Tk()
#window.title("Preview Window")

count = 0
for f in os.listdir(fileLocation):

    if f.endswith(".JPG") or f.endswith(".jpg"):

        #Opening the Image
        imageAddress = str(fileLocation)+ "\\" + str(f)
        print(str(imageAddress))
        im1 = im2 = Image.open(imageAddress)
        print("Image Opened: "+str(f))

        #setting the watermark size
        wmSize = im1.size
        print("Image Size: "+str(wmSize))
        wNew = whiteWatermark.resize(wmSize)
        print("White Watermark Size: "+str(wNew.size))
        bNew = blackWatermark.resize(wmSize)
        print("Black Watermark Size: "+str(bNew.size))

        im1.paste(wNew,(0,0),wNew)
        print("White Watermark Placed")
        im2.paste(bNew,(0,0),bNew)
        print("Black Watermark Placed")

        saveLocation = r"C:\Users\Rockw\Desktop\Python\Modified Photos"
        fileName = "\WM("+ str(count) +").JPG"
        saveName = saveLocation + fileName
        print("White Watermark Save Name: "+saveName)
        im1.save(saveName)

        count+=1

        fileName = "\WM("+ str(count) +").JPG"
        saveName = saveLocation + fileName
        print("Black Watermark Save Name: "+saveName)
        im2.save(saveName)

        print("New Images Saved")
        print("------------------------------")


        count+=1

print("All Files Edited")           







root = Tk()

fileLabel = Label(root,text="File Location").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
fileEntry = Entry(root,width=50)
fileEntry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

watermarkButton = Button(root,text="Watermark")
watermarkButton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
watermarkButton.bind("<Button-1>",watermark)

bwButton = Button(root,text="Black and White").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the code.. It isn't very pretty I apologize

Edit: Added all of the code rather than the snippet i had before

Comment: Also, could you post the code where you're opening the image? Thanks.

Comment: And duplicating it to `im1` and `im2`

Comment: `im1` and `im2` are names for objects. It seems they are names for the same object. You need to show us where you assign the object to a name.

Comment: @Zeokav definitely not OpenCV. Pretty sure it's PIL.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds no wonder I couldn't figure out what the paste method was (the rest are there in opencv as well!)

Comment: @Zeokav yeah but they're not methods of a numpy type, so it would be `resize(image, size)` and imwrite(filename, image)` not `image.resize(size)` and `image.save(filename)`.

Comment: Sure thing, ill edit the OP and put the program in.. I wasn't sure how necessary all of it was... And yes im using Pillow

Comment: Also if the code isn't as efficient or just wrong (which is very well might be) I literally started python two days ago and i didnt really start with a beginners tutorial.. I just watched Youtube and used Stack Overflow to get this much.. serves its purpose to add a watermark, I just wanted to add more functionality